# I am trying to get Max function working but it returns null followed by decimal numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get five employees who have the highest commision_pct in their city. However, it always returns null as the highest value.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name , city, max(commission_pct)
FROM employees, locations
where ROWNUM <= 5
group by first_name,employees.last_name, city
order by Max(commission_pct) ASC
```

```
Steven  King    Bombay  null
Steven  King    Geneva  null
Steven  King    Beijing null
Steven  King    Bern    null
Steven  King    Hiroshima   null
```

It always returns Steven even though there are different employees.

Comment: You have no join between `employees` and `locations` - something that would not have happened if you had used an explicit `JOIN` operator

Comment: what is the join condition between two tables?

Comment: The biggest mistake is your GROUP BY clause. Why are you including the employee first and last name in GROUP BY? This will cause different employees (or, rather, employees with different names) to ALWAYS fall in DIFFERENT, separate groups. Surely that is not what you want??

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- you have a Cartesian product between the tables. Use modern join syntax to help prevent that happening by accident.
- there is no direct link between employees and locations; you need to go through departments.
- you are ordering by ascending values, so lower values come first.
- you should order *before* applying a `rownum` limit. At the moment you are picking five indeterminate (not quite random, but close enough) results from your Cartesian product, all of which happen to have no commission and so show as null; and then you are ordering those five. You are not picking the five highest.
- you don't need to aggregate as there are no duplicates.

So you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, l.city, e.commission_pct
  FROM employees e
  JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
  JOIN locations l ON l.location_id = d.location_id
  ORDER BY e.commission_pct DESC NULLS LAST
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;

FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 CITY                           COMMISSION_PCT
-------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------------ --------------
John                 Russell                   Oxford                                     .4
Janette              King                      Oxford                                    .35
Allan                McEwen                    Oxford                                    .35
Patrick              Sully                     Oxford                                    .35
Karen                Partners                  Oxford                                     .3
```

Oracle 12c+ has `fetch` syntax to avoid the explicit `rownum` filter:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, l.city, e.commission_pct
FROM employees e
JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
JOIN locations l ON l.location_id = d.location_id
ORDER BY e.commission_pct DESC NULLS LAST
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Something else you need to consider is how to deal with ties; there are seven employees with commission of 0.3, so this can only show one of those; and which one is currently indeterminate.

You said "five employees who have the highest commission_pct in their city", which means (I think) that you want five employees listed for every city; but only sales have commission, and they are only in Oxford, so the result would be the same. But just to show that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, l.city, e.commission_pct,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY l.city ORDER BY e.commission_pct DESC) AS rnk
  FROM employees e
  JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
  JOIN locations l ON l.location_id = d.location_id
  WHERE e.commission_pct IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE rnk <= 5
ORDER BY city, rnk;
```

Because I used `rank()` that returns 11 rows, including all the tied fifth-place employees. With `dense_rank()` it would return 24 rows, for all the employees with any of the five highest commissions. With `row_number()` it would return 5 rows again - including one, still indeterminate, row for 0.3.

Comment: The OP described the problem in words. Right at the top he talks about highest commission percentage BY CITY. So aggregation is in fact needed, just not the way the OP did it.

Comment: See, though, my second comment under the OP's question. He says "in their city" - but the only city with employees with non-NULL commission percentage is Oxford. So the whole thing is nonsensical.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that, and that there is only one city, so that distinction is pointless. But the rank version will deal with it anyway?

Comment: I was referring to the last point at the top of your answer: "You don't need to aggregate as there are no duplicates". There ARE duplicates in the CITY column (after the joins), and if the OP needs to pick five employees who are each "top commission pct" "in their city", then aggregation is needed. Or something similar to it, like an analytic function (such as RANK() as you showed)

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
select * from
(
SELECT first_name, last_name , city, max(commission_pct)
FROM employees, locations
group by first_name,employees.last_name, city
order by Max(commission_pct) ASC  
) 
where ROWNUM <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the highest commision then ordering must be in `DESC` order. Also, you need join condition between two tables.

```
select * from
(
SELECT first_name, last_name , city, max(commission_pct)
FROM employees join locations
on (enter join condition here)
group by first_name, last_name, city
order by Max(commission_pct) desc nulls last  
) 
where ROWNUM <= 5
```

Cheers!!